# How to say "I take dancing classes" or "I'm learning dancing"

Tags: translation

How do you say "I'm learning dancing" or "I take dancing classes"?

Is this correct?

> watashi wa dansu wo benkyou desu

Comment: Would like to point out that the particle wo normally means a verb follows (such as narau (naratte imasu)) as mackygoo below has suggested. benkyou by itself is a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"watashi wa dansu wo benkyou desu" is not correct.

As for "I take dancing classes", you say in Japanese;
watashi wa dansu kyoushitsu ni kayotte imasu.
私はダンス教室(class)に通っています。

And, for "I'm learning dancing", you say;
watashi wa dansu wo naratte imasu.
私はダンスを習っています。